# How to safely remove hard-link to home folder?

Tags: directory-structure, rm, hard-link

In a folder owned by my user `/sites/Website` there is a dir named `~`.

When I `cd` to this directory, I am redirected to `~/`, my home folder.

At first I thought this was a symbolic link, but doing `ls -al` shows it to be ordinary. I'm assuming it is a hard link. I ran:

```
$ rm -r /sites/Website/~
```

This began to actually delete my home folder and I lost a lot of data. I stopped `rm` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. How can I get rid of this link safely?

Comment: In Linux, hard links to directories are not allowed (except for `.` and `..`), so it is probably not a hardlink. What is the output of `stat ~ /sites/Website/~`?

Comment: You can't make hardlinks to directories. `/sites/Website/~` shouldn't expand to `$HOME`. Did you actually change to `/sites/Website` and run `rm -r ~`?

Comment: Try quoting or escaping the directory name when you use it (`\~` or `'~'`). That way, your shell won't expand the tilde to `$HOME`.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman Even "~" does.

Comment: check the output of `mount`, maybe it's the same directory mounted to two places?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman Quoting the directory name completely solved my problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: Another pitfall for bash beginners: If you rename a directory like `mv some_dir '$HOME'`you suddenly have a directory which seems to behave like a hard link to the home directory in the bash. This may produce unexpected results in combination with `rm -r` :-).

Answer (score 4):

Many shells expand a leading tilde character (`~`) before a slash at
the start of a pathname into the absolute path of your HOME directory.
You can prevent this shell expansion by quoting the tilde character or by
making sure the tilde doesn't start the pathname:

```
$ echo "$HOME"
/home/idallen
$ echo ~
/home/idallen
$ echo "~"
~
$ echo \~
~
$ echo ./~
./~
```

There is nothing special about a tilde character to Unix itself, so you
can create a directory named tilde, provided you hide the tilde from
expansion by the shell using any of the above methods:

```
$ mkdir "~"
$ ls -ld '~'
drwxr-xr-x 2 idallen idallen 40 Oct 22 08:45 ~
$ ls -ld \~
drwxr-xr-x 2 idallen idallen 40 Oct 22 08:45 ~
$ ls -ld ./~
drwxr-xr-x 2 idallen idallen 40 Oct 22 08:45 ~
$ ls -ld /tmp/idallen/~
drwxr-xr-x 2 idallen idallen 40 Oct 22 08:45 /tmp/idallen/~
```

If you don't hide the leading tilde character from the shell, the shell
expands it to be your HOME directory.  Adding an `echo` command in front
of a command line can show you what the shell does to your command line
before it is executed:

```
$ echo cd ~
cd /home/idallen                 # would go to $HOME directory
$ echo cd ./~
cd ./~                           # would go into directory named ~
```

You have discovered this need for quoting the tilde, because the commands
below would have very different effects, depending on your shell expanding
an unquoted leading tilde:

```
$ echo rm -r ~       
rm -r /home/idallen              # would remove the $HOME directory
$ echo rm -r "~"
rm -r ~                          # would remove the directory named ~
$ echo rm -r ./~
rm -r ./~                        # would remove the directory named ~
$ echo rm -r /tmp/idallen/~
rm -r /tmp/idallen/~             # would remove the directory named ~
```

Only unquoted tildes at the start of pathnames expand to be your HOME directory.